# How to get Azure File Shares Directory Statistics?

Tags: function, azure, file, file-storage

I'm setting up Azure file sync to Sync files to Azure File shares. How do I check the directory statistics?

I tried using "Storage Explorer(preview)" at Azure Portal to get the file shares directory statistics, but there are so many files under file shares, it had taken more five hours and met an error. I had tried three times but every time was the same error.

I expect to get the Azure Files Share Directory Statistics separately but Storage Explorer usually ends with an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Storage Explorer (preview)` is a preview version, you could download the [`Azure Storage Explorer`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to local, [connect to your storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows) and have a try.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but when I  clicked file shares there show an error `The requested action could not be completed.`  `Details: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND fileshare1.file.core.windows.net  fileshare1.file.core.windows.net:443`

Comment: @Arthur Did you connect to your storage account with SAS URI? Do you have the permission to access the file shares? Also make sure you use the latest version explorer, try to reconnect your account?

Comment: Yes, I used SAS URI, I have the permission to access the file shares. Maybe I found the reason, it's because of the proxy setting, thanks so much.

Comment: @Arthur You are welcome, gald to know you solve it.